# What is the use of pause() function here (regarding raspberry pi) and why it is written in the end?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

What is the use of pause() function here (regarding raspberry pi) and why it is written in the end?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import os, sys

offGPIO = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else 21

holdTime = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 6

# the function called to shut down the RPI

def shutdown():`enter code here`
    os.system("sudo poweroff")

btn = Button(offGPIO, hold_time=holdTime)

btn.when_held = shutdown

pause()    # handle the button presses in the background
```

Answer (score 2):

> Cause the process to sleep until a signal is received; the appropriate
>   handler will then be called. Returns nothing. Not on Windows. (See the
>   Unix man page signal(2).)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.pause

Comment: thanx :) one more query ! Can I use an infinite loop rather than using pause() ?